# Run Code when AngularJS has an Error

Tags: angularjs

**Question**: How can you run code when Angular has an error like `Uncaught Error: [$injector:moduler]`

**Story**: Our team would like to be notified when a user has an error with our angular application. We already have a setup if an $http request has an error we have a $httpProvider.interceptors that catches the error and notifies us about the error and who had it, which works great. The problem is we don't have any way of being notified when an angular error happens.

**What we have tried**: I first thought Angular used console.error so I tried something like this.

```
console.errorBack = console.error;
console.error = function(){
    //notify us about the error
    console.errorBack.apply(null,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};
```

Which I found does not work as Angular does not use console.error for there error messaging system. So I looked at the source code for Angular but I could not find the code that controls the error system to append to it.

Comment: without looking, angular probably uses $log https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log.

Comment: Have you looked at $exceptionHandler?